# where is ess version 19.04?

Tags: emacs, knitr, ess

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17063/how-to-setup-knitr-workflow-in-emacs recommends 
version 19.04 as the setup for Knitr is much simplified. However I can't find version 19.04

http://ess.r-project.org/ has version 18.10.2 and links to a development version, 18.10.3snapshot, on github. It describes version 19.04 as "unreleased."

Comment: I just fund this: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/milestone/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to add my own answer to this, as I was deeply confused.

As far as I can tell, in a technical sense "ESS 19.04" **does not exist** - when people refer to ESS 19.04 they mean "the current development version of ESS", which lives [here](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS). The VERSION file there currently (September 2022) lists 18.10.3snapshot; the version number hasn't changed since 2018 even though there's been a lot of development since then.

The [news file](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/news.html) on the ESS page discusses 19.04 extensively, and lots of web resources refer to version 19.04 ... but good luck finding it!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045390/j-f

Yes, https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/milestone/1 records ess 19.04
as 75% complete  with "No due date".